# How to return the last element of a list with a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

I need to extract the last character from each line based on this list:

```
lst = [ '-ae-' , '-ap-' , '-vn-' , '-au-' , '-aw-' , '-be-' , '-bp-' , '-br-' , '-dz-' ]
```

Here a sample of the `df['CN']` :

```
1: aes-sof-mar-goo-wh-en-ap-bro-sear-vn-loc
2: aes-br-mar-goo-ww-en-dz-bp-cen 
3: aes-apt-au-goo-vn-en-br-bp
```

I used this code :

```
def param(df):
    lst = ['-ae-','-ap-','-vn-','-au-','-aw-','-be-','-bp-','-br-', '-dz-']
    for x in lst: 
        if x in df['CN']:
            return x

df['budget'] = df.apply(param, axis=1)
```

I need to return the last element seen on the list :

```
1: -vn-
2: -bp-
3: -bp-
```

but my code returned the first element crossed of each line:

```
1: -ap-
2: -br-
3: -au-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas way, using [`series.str.findall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and [`series.str()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html):

```
pat=r'(?=({}))'.format('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in lst))# @thanks Amadan
#'(?=(\\-ae\\-|\\-ap\\-|\\-vn\\-|\\-au\\-|\\-aw\\-|\\-be\\-|\\-bp\\-|\\-br\\-|\\-dz\\-))'
df['CN'].str.findall(pat).str[-1]
```

---

```
0    -vn-
1    -dz-
2    -br-
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rfind` to find the rightmost occurence. Use `max` to find the rightmost rightmost occurence. This code assumes at least one `lst` member will be found; if none are found, it will return a `lst` member anyway.

```
def param(df):
    lst = ['-ae-','-ap-','-vn-','-au-','-aw-','-be-','-bp-','-br-', '-dz-']
    return max(lst, key=lambda x: rfind(df, x))
```

This is longer, but will return `None` when it makes sense:

```
def param(df):
    lst = ['-ae-','-ap-','-vn-','-au-','-aw-','-be-','-bp-','-br-', '-dz-']
    pos = [(rfind(df, x), x) for x in lst]
    if not pos: return None
    m = max(pos)
    if m[0] == -1: return None
    return m[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

using [np.in1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html)

```
l = [i.replace('-','') for i in lst]
df['CN'].apply(lambda x: '-'+ np.array(l)[np.in1d(l,x.split('-'))][-1] + '-')
```

**Output**

```
0    -vn-
1    -dz-
2    -br-
```

Comment: Awesome! It'd probably be even a smidgen faster if you extract arrayification of `l`: `l = np.array([i.replace('-','') for i in lst])` rather than doing it in every lambda invocation.